# textual representation of day of the week from numeric representation

Tags: php, date

i need convert Numeric representation of the day of the week to textual representation of the day of the week.

ex - 0 - sunday, 1 - monday

```
date('w') -> date('l');
```

I can do it using simple array like this.

```
$date = 1;

$dates = array(
    0 => 'sunday',
    1 => 'monday',
    2 => 'tuesday',
    3 => 'wednesday',
    4 => 'thursday',
    5 => 'friday',
    6 => 'saturday',
);

echo $dates[$date]; //monday
```

But i need to know is this best way? How can i do it using php library function?

Improve the question.

I just find code like this.

```
echo date('l', strtotime(date('w')); //this code should invalid.
```

Comment: What is the problem with `date('l')`?

Comment: That looks good to me

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why not just use date('l') ?

Comment: [Use `echo $dates[date('w')];`](https://eval.in/236594)

Comment: i enhance the question. please see

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting the current day of the week you can just use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function like so:  `date('l')`.

If you're looking for a day of the week based on a specific number you provide than the way you show is a acceptable way to do it:

```
function dayFromNumber($day)
{
    $dates = array(
        0 => 'sunday',
        1 => 'monday',
        2 => 'tuesday',
        3 => 'wednesday',
        4 => 'thursday',
        5 => 'friday',
        6 => 'saturday',
    );
    return $dates[$day]
}


echo dayFromNumber(1); // Would echo monday
```